# How to retrieve the query parameters from camel message?

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse

I am passing the username & password in the SOAP based webservice 
url and trying to retrieve it in a custom InInterceptor. But no success. 
Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please provide more detail about how you are trying to do it?

Comment: Have you checked if username and password exists in camel headers and body ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for writing a CXF inbound interceptor and how to grab the standard HTTP username and password (not the SOAP WS-Security UsernameToken!)

http://www.mastertheboss.com/javaee/jboss-web-services/jax-ws-basic-authentication